# Nock: nock.load does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nock

I am trying to load a JSON file that contains a mock response with the Nock function: `nock.load(filePath)`. Oddly, the test fails with error:

> TypeError: nockDefs.forEach is not a function

If I replace the `nock.load` call with raw JSON, the test runs fine. This is my test code:

```js
describe('Sample description', function () {

  it('sample desc', function () {
    this.timeout(0);
    nock("https://sample.url.com")
    .get('/endpoint')
    .reply(200, nock.load('tests/responses/get_response_200.json'));

    return api
      .getResponse()
      .then(res => expect(res).to.be({
          first_name: "Ada",
          last_name: "Obi"
      }
   ));

  })
})
```

I have verified that my JSON file contains valid JSON and I've even tried experimenting with simpler JSON structures but the **same error message** persists.

I am using the latest version of nock at this time: **13.1.0**. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nock.load` is for importing recorded Nock responses, not loading arbitrary JSON.

What you want is [`.replyWithFile()`](https://github.com/nock/nock/#specifying-replies):

```
nock("https://sample.url.com")
  .get('/endpoint')
  .replyWithFile(200, 'tests/responses/get_response_200.json')
```

Or, you can load and parse the JSON yourself, either using `require()` or `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('tests/responses/get_response_200.json', 'utf-8'))`.